# Output string property verbatim to prevent double encoding

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have the following code:

```
var data = new {
    A = "{\"X\": 5}",
    B = new {Y = 6}
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

This results in:

```
{
    "A": "{\"X\": 5}",
    "B": {Y: 6}
}
```

However, what I need is (without the quotes on `A`):

```
{
    "A": {"X": 5},
    "B": {"Y": 6}
}
```

In reality, my `A` property has a very complex JSON string that is already serialized by another system.

A workaround would be to de-serialize my `A` property first, and let JSON.NET to serialize it back, however this is wasteful and obfuscates the intent of the code.

How do I tell JSON.NET to use the string representation of a property for serialization instead of serializing it for me?

EDIT:

My original thought was to create a new type called `JsonVerbatim` that wraps a string and have a custom converter for this new type that outputs that string directly.

Comment: I am not sure about the *intent* of the code, If I have input as `"{X: 5}"` and in the JSON I get the values without double quotes, I would be more confused.

Comment: Perhaps a custom converter with the `JsonConverter` attribute applied just to that property?

Comment: @Habib I am not intending on all strings would have this behavior, just certain ones that I don't want to be encoded to a javascript string.

Comment: Quick and easy way (yes it's deserializing and then reserializing): `var data = new { A = JObject.Parse("{X: 5}"), ...  }`

Comment: Also I'm assuming what you've posted is just an example, but in this case `A`'s value isn't actually valid JSON. You'd need `"X"` to be quoted inside of the string.

Comment: True, my example is not valid JSON, fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could:

```
public class LiteralStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        object value = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        string value2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        return value2;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string str = (string)value;
        writer.WriteRawValue(str);
    }
}
```

then

```
public class MyObject
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(LiteralStringConverter))]
    public string A { get; set; }

    public object B;
}
```

and then:

```
var data = new MyObject
{
    A = "{X: 5}",
    B = new { Y = 6 }
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

And back:

```
var data2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);
```

Note that while serialization is now "optimized", deserialization is doubly slower, because I deserialize to `object` to then reserialize to `string`.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thank you.  I'm not concerned about the deserialization performance as it's not needed in my scenario, but it's nice to know for the future.